# How to define transfer function as function in s

Tags: matlab

In control systems, we use transfer functions a lot. One way to define transfer function is merely to use tf(). For example, we could define such transfer function as

```
s=tf('s');
G=(s+1)/(s+3);
```

But what I would like to do is to define G as G(s) without explicitly defining the underlying transfer function and treat it as  transfer function so that I can use Control Toolbox (i.e. feedback(), series(), parallel(),...,etc)  to carry out some manipulations. How one can achieve this ? For example,